# How to respond_to AJAX call without erb.js / why use erb.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

The last few days I've spent trying to understand different facets of AJAX on rails. After reading some introductions I've managed to get an idea of the rails built-in UJS feature. An example from a small toy app I wrote and where I want to introduce some AJAX-capability...

The controller action looks as follows

```
class ExpenseListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_authentication

  ...

  def create
    @expense_list = ExpenseList.new(expense_list_params)
    if @expense_list.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          flash[:success] = 'Created!'
          render :show
        end
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          @errors = @expense_list.errors
          flash[:danger] = 'Something went wrong!'
          render :new
        end
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

In my view I call the action via the `remote: true` option

The respective `create.js.erb` looks like this

```
var form_field = $('.expense_lists_form');
var expenseLists = $('#expense-lists');

expenseLists.append("<%= j render @expense_list %>");
form_field.slideUp(200);
```

The template for `@expense_list` looks like this

```
.col-xs-12.col-lg-3.col-md-4{id: "expense_list_#{expense_list.id}"}
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      = link_to expense_list.name, expense_list_path(expense_list)
    .panel-body
      .links
        = link_to 'Modify list', edit_expense_list_path(expense_list), remote: true
        = link_to 'Delete list', expense_list_path(expense_list), method: 'delete', remote: true
      .description
      %p
      - if expense_list.description.present?
        = expense_list.description
      - else
        %i
          No description supplied, add one
          =link_to 'here', edit_expense_list_path(expense_list)
      .email-notification.text-muted
        (Email notifications enabled)
    .panel-footer
      = "Expenses in #{current_month_name}:"
      %b
        = "#{expense_list.sum_of_exp_in_month(current_month, current_year)}€"
      = "(#{expense_list.euros_left_in_month(current_month, current_year)}€ left)" if expense_list.budget_in_euro
```

It works but to me this idea seems to have some down-sides:

- Bloats my file structure by having extra *.js.erb files
- Distorts the physical separation of JS and the rest of the codebase
- As I use HAML it introduces a new style of coding (ERB)

Now I have two questions:

1. Every tutorial (I've seen so far) seems to promote this kind of solution for handling AJAX responses in Rails: Why? When I check the code of other, larger rails projects (e.g. Diaspora) I do not seem to find them do it this way - most of them seem to handle it inside plain JS/jQuery via `$.ajax({ ... })`. So what would be the major advantages of the rails-internal UJS approach?
2. If the rails UJS-way is preferrable for some reason: How do you organise your code? Create extra directories for the `*.js.erb`-files?
3. What would be a good practice to transfer all this stuff to plain javascript files located in my `/app/assets/javascript` directory and handle the AJAX requests within jQuery there? How would my controller response have to look like in order to respond with the proper portion of HTML to update the DOM with via JS? In other words: How can I respond with a partial that I can handle in Plain Javascript/jQuery?

Thanks in advance!
Andi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So what would be the major advantages of the rails-internal UJS approach?

`js.erb` is a form of a poor mans Single Page Architecture (SPA).

It makes it just easy enough to return `.js` responses from your controller which modify the current page and lets you use the rails helpers for templating so that you don't have to use a client side templating system such as handlebars.

Note that this is not really internal to rails. jQuery UJS simple uses the fact that rails can return multiple formats of a resource. You could potentially use this with any MVC frameworks that can serve javascript.

The main advantage is that it is very approachable. 
Its just enough for classic syncronous apps that want a few sprinkles of ajax here and there.

It gives developers who think `jQuery.load` and script tags everywhere is the best thing since sliced bread just enough rope to hang themselves with.

### The cons

- Violates REST as `js.erb` views are usually used as procedures to manipulate the current page.
- the javascript in a  `js.erb` view is not minified by the assets pipeline as it served per request.
- It leads to horrible architecture decisions.

### Whats the alternative?

Long before `jquery-ujs` entered the scene we had already figured out that the best way to do ajax requests is JSON.

So if you want to send a form asynchronously you would do:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.ajax-form', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  var promise = $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
    accepts: { json: 'application/json' },
    data: $form.serialize(),
    context: $form,
    method: $form.attr('method')
  });
  promise.done(function(response){
    // handle the response
  });
});
```

This way the javascript logic can be concatenated into a single file, and tested separately in javascript testing tools.

Your backend server just responds with simple data and does not concern itself with what the client does with it.

However this does require you to setup some sort of templating on the client side to handle converting JSON to HTML and you need to setup stuff like data bindings to have your form display errors. This leads to code duplication.

This is where SPA frameworks like Ember and Angular come into the picture which do all the templating and rendering in the client.

### How can I respond with a partial that I can handle in Plain Javascript/jQuery?

You could create add additional formats which your controller responds to. You could for example register a `"text/html-partial"` mime type.

Or create additional routes or even use a query param (shudder).

However this is less than ideal for the exact same reason as `js.erb` - it leads to a crappy API as your controllers will become process instead of resource oriented. You will end up creating ridiculous controller actions just to pass html fragments back to the client.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your oppinion on that. It sounds as if either I have to live with horrible architecture decisions (what are these specifically?) OR use frameworks like Angular in order to handle templating, did I undestand you about correct? Is it possible to realize templating with less overhead through libraries like mustache.js or the like?

Comment: The horrible architecture designs with `.js.erb` is that often leads you away from building RESTfully and into this soup of `do_foo_to_bar` style remote proceedure calls. There is no clear separation of responsibility and as the complexity level increases your javascript becomes really hard to follow as the flow is spread everywhere. Its basically like having a bunch of script tags. Except that the script tags have huge HTML strings in them.

Comment: Its not a black and white decision between JS.erb and a "full stack" SPA  - if you only need ajax for certain features in an otherwise "classical" app - you can very well build a lighter stack on handlebars for templating and backbone for data bindings.

Comment: You can even just just use underscore/lodash `.template` or build node trees with jQuery.  It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Problem is: I'm not quite sure about my requirements. So far I consider the little project a toy app but who knows how big it will become (i have some ideas...). But what you're saying about the spread of flow. Still, I wonder why everybody is promoting the `.js.erb` design (btw: is there a technical term for that?) and not any other? Is it because of the nature of introductory articles which normally only refer to toy apps?

Comment: Its because its easier to write articles about scaffolded blog applications. Thats where `.js.erb` shines. And there is no real technical term AFAIK - its just a software pattern that uses jquery-ujs and JS responses from rails. There are tons of articles on for example Rails + Backbone as its more approachable than doing everything from scratch.

Comment: Allright, thanks a lot max, that should suffice as a first input!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125343/discussion-between-a-neumann-and-max).